# Spring webservice: validate that a timestamp is signed

Tags: spring, spring-ws

In my SOAP webservice, we agreed that the body is signed. For that, I use Spring, configured like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor" id="wsSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="validationActions" value="Timestamp Signature"/>
    <property name="timestampStrict" value="true"/>
    <property name="validationSignatureCrypto">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
            <property name="configuration">
                <props>
                    <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">JKS</prop>
                    <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">${ws.security.truststore.location}</prop>
                    <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">${ws.security.truststore.password}</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But now, I'm asked to also check that the timestamp is correctly signed.

When I read [Spring's documentation on the matter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html), I can see how to **sign** a timestamp, but nowhere is it mentioned how to **validate** a timestamp signature.

So anyone knows how I can do that?

If that's any indication, I use `org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:2.1.2.RELEASE`.

Comment: Based on what I see from WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader() and SignatureProcessor,handleToken(). I think that SignatureProcessor will also validate the signature of the timestamp.

Comment: @VirtualTroll Sorry, we've put this on hold temporarily. We're back on it. We're gonna test your suggestion today. If that works, I'll ask to make an answer out of your comment so I can give you proper credit.